# @HTML.ActionLink and @URL.Action not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I must be missing something simple here but I don't understand what's going on with my Links in my Razor pages?

I've tried both of these to create a link to my Controller/ActionResult which is should be Gallery/Index.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Here", "Index", "Gallery", null, null)

<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Gallery")">Click here</a>
```

When I use these and look at the Page Source it is creating the following links.

```
<a href="/Gallery">Click Here</a>

<a href="/Gallery">Click here</a> to see examples of our work.
```

If click on either one of them I get this error message:

```
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.
```

However, if I browse directly to /Gallery/Index then the page works fine.

Why won't these ActionLink or UrlAction not create a link like "/Gallery/Index"?

Comment: Best guess is you also have a folder in your solution named `Gallery`?

Comment: is it in root of project or in area?

Comment: Check if `GalleryController` class contains default `Index` action method, even generated HTML `href` attribute doesn't mention `Index` as its target action.

Comment: @StephenMuecke.....bingo. That was it. I did have a folder named Gallery as well as my controller name was Gallery. Changed the folder to GalleryImages and it worked as expected. Lesson learned. Thanks!

Comment: @Caverman Did you try my answer?

Comment: Yes I tried most of those even before posting my question. The issue was what @StephenMuecke had suggested. I had a folder named Gallery as well as a controller named Gallery. I now know you can't do that. Changed the folder name and it worked as expected.

Comment: Why is this even being downvoted is a mystery to me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `@Html.ActionLink` according to your needs as show below :

***Default:***

```
@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Gallery")
```

***Using Button:***

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Gallery")';
    return false;">Click Here</button>
```

**With Parameters:**

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Gallery",new { Model.Id})';
    return false;">Click Here</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" title="Click Here" value="Click Here" 
    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Gallery", new { id = item.Id })'" />
```

***Using Hyperlink:***

```
<a href="/Gallery/Index/123">Click Here</a>
```

**Using Image:**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Gallery", new { id = item.Id })" title="Click Here">
<img src="../Content/Images/gallery.png" />
```